# Angular JS form with a checkbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular form with a checkbox.

The problem is: it does not work, I do not know where the problem is.

```html
<div class="inmodal">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <i class="fa fa-laptop modal-icon"></i>
        <h4 class="modal-title">PDF</h4>
        <small class="font-bold"></small>
    </div>
 <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary"><input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox" ng-model="getZZ6533"><label for="checkbox2">ZZ6533</label></div>
       <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary"><input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox" ng-model="getHH1213"><label for="checkbox2">HH1213</label></div>
       <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary"><input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox" ng-model="getMM9090Alt"><label for="checkbox2">MM9090Alt</label></div>
       <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary"><input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox" ng-model="getXL7878"><label for="checkbox2">XL7878</label></div>
            
       </div>                          
    
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-white" ng-click="cancel()">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" ng-click="checkoptions(arrlist)">RUN</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please post the javascript code?

Comment: All checkboxes have the same id

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work" what are you expecting it to do? You need to paste the complete code.

Comment: As mentioned above, all checkboxes have the same ID, which should be unique. As for does not work, do you mean that the data is not sent back to your controller? If you do, you probably want something more like arrlist.getXL7878 for your models, and then the checkoptions argument will have an object with the checked items.

Answer (score 0):

```
 function PdfllCtrl($scope, $http, DTOptionsBuilder, localStorageService, $uibModal){

    var date = localStorageService.get('daterange');
    $scope.page = "1";

    $http({
         method: 'GET',
         url: apiurl + "GetPDFll?fromDate="+date.startDate+"&toDate="+date.endDate+" 23:59:59&pageIndex="+$scope.page+"&search=",
         headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }).then(function(response){
         $scope.Entries = response.data[0].Results;
    });


$scope.getZZ6533 = function ( oid ){
    $scope.Oid = oid;

    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: apiurl + "getZZ6533?Oid="+$scope.Oid,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        responseType:'arraybuffer'
    }).success(function(response){
        var file = new Blob( [response], {type: 'application/pdf'} );
        var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        window.open(fileURL);
    });
  };

  $scope.getHH1213 = function ( oid ){
    $scope.Oid = oid;

    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: apiurl + "getHH1213?Oid="+$scope.Oid,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        responseType:'arraybuffer'
    }).success(function(response){
        var file = new Blob( [response], {type: 'application/pdf'} );
        var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        window.open(fileURL);
    });
```

};

Comment: You have these methods, and then you're trying to tie them to the checkbox somehow as a the model.  That's not going to work.  You're binding each checkbox to a function, which Angular will do fine. Maybe you intended to invoke this method on the ng-click of the checkbox?